# Editing embeds by selecting from a select menu in discord.js V13

Tags: discord.js

is there a way to make the bot edit the messages of an embed after selecting an option from a select menu?
Like if the message on the embed is: **"Fruit"**,
If you choose **Mango** in the select menu, the embed's text would edit to **"Mango"**.
If you choose **Apple** in the select menu, the embed's text would edit to **"Apple"**.

And, for more information, the embed and the select menu is in the same message.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do that. Have you tried anything? What do you have problem with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for example if you use the interactionCreate event like so :

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction =>{
 // First we make sure it's the right select menu
  if(interaction.customId !== "your_select_menu_id") return;

 // ...
})
```

We can get the selected option using the `values` property which is an array and getting the first element.

```js
let selected = interaction.values[0]
```

Then we simply edit the message's content to the selected variable

```js
await interaction.message.edit({ content : selected })
```